# Retrieve events hosted by a group with FQL

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql, facebook-events, facebook-group

I would like to know how do events hosted by a group connect to that group so I can retrieve all events from a specific group (all I have the group id). 
This needs to be done using FQL and PHP SDK (I know my way with these, but I am unable to find anything about connections between groups and events).

Answer (score 3):

Meanwhile, GROUP_ID/events works pretty well for me here.

It was possible with REST API if you look at this:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/events.get/

They say:
"The uid can be replaced by gid in order to get events hosted by a group instead of by an individual user."

I tried to get events of groups I have joined via the Graph API Explorer and it worked as well as a little restFB (Java) implementation I made.

So, could it be a permission issue at your site?

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't look like you can pull that off.

The documentation of the [Group object](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/group/) does not mention a collection of events, and if you try to get */GROUPID/events* from the graph api you get an error saying "Unsupported get request".

The fql documentation of the [group table](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/group/) also has nothing on events, and the [event table](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/event/) is only indexed by the event id which means that there's no way to connect between events and groups.

Comment: Well... nothing new (I did a search through facebook docs before posting the question). I was expecting something that I CAN do, not something that they don't provide.    Considering the fact that events get displayed on the group page, there MUST be some connection between them (as you said, the GRAPH API does not recognize/support */GROUPID/events* calls). I am thinking FQL as it does the request at the database table level, and not to some **GET** calls (which needs url interpretation, etc.).

Comment: Facebook does not offer you all of the data/connection it has, and I doubt that the fql tables actually represent real db tables, it's just another api for querying data from the graph. May ask what it you want to do with the data? Maybe there's another approach.

Comment: The task is to get all events hosted by a group (all I have is group ID) and display them on a website. Not so difficult, but, then again, no so easy at all.

Comment: Sorry, in that case I'm not aware of how you can accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

Up until a couple of weeks ago the following would do exactly what you need

```
SELECT name FROM event WHERE eid IN
(SELECT eid FROM event_member WHERE uid = <uid from group>)
```

but the api changed to using group objects so the code does not work anymore. Sadly, I have not found another way to get the events from a specific group.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook has broken this one before. : (

Will see if I can trace down how we got it fixed last time.

---

In the mean time, the closest I could get is:

[https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT eid, name, host FROM event WHERE eid IN (SELECT eid FROM event_member WHERE uid = **$uid** AND start_time > 0) AND host = '**$group_name**'&access_token=**$token**](https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT%20eid,%20name,%20host%20FROM%20event%20WHERE%20eid%20IN%20%28SELECT%20eid%20FROM%20event_member%20WHERE%20uid%20=%20%24uid%20AND%20start_time%20%3E%200%29%20AND%20host%20=%20%27%24group_name%27&access_token=%24token)

Variables:

- **$uid** = uid of a group admin
- **$group_name** = name of the group
- **$token** = access token for the above group admin with user_events permission

Only downsides I can see are:

1. An auth token is required (even for a public group); and
2. The admin used must be invited to all events (this is usually the case anyway). If the admin isn't invited, it appears that the event won't show up.

---

**Update:** Facebook bug report - please add your support so we can get this fixed:
http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/197158423732088

Answer (score 0):

Try the updated Wallflux-events: http://wallflux.com/events/115227675156013